# NSDateFormatter: error in converting date

Tags: ios, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter, epoch

I have got the following time stamp in milliseconds:

```
    NSDate * date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1470524933.923123];
    NSDate * date2 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1470666561.000];

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString * dateInString  = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```

When I run it I get the following:

> **2016-08-07 at 00:08:53**, 2016-08-08 at 15:29:21

However the first date should be as following according to the [epoch time converter website I am using](http://www.epochconverter.com/):

> Your time zone: 8/7/2016, **12:08:53** AM GMT+1:00 DST

**It says 00 rather than 12. Why is that?**

Comment: 12 AM is for midnight, no ?

Comment: Right. I had missed that :). Thanks

Comment: You're formatting the date in 24 hour format (HH). If you want 12 hour and AM/PM set the date format accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the `TimeZone` of your `NSDateFormatter` to `GMT`

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

As larme and vadian suggested if you want 12 for hour use this format

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a"];
```